# Is the Rails ecosystem a suitable replacement for drupal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drupal

I want to make a community based site, which is Drupal's strength. However I also want to try other frameworks, especially Rails.

One of the best things about drupal is its huge modules library. If I were to switch to Rails, would I be able to find similar functionality freely available as plugins, or would I have to rebuild?

Does Rails have the equivalent of (as plugins or gems):

```
CCK/Fields?
Node Reference?
Views / Views Relationships?
PathAuto?
Threaded Commenting?
Multisite Functionality?
Apache Solr (or equivalent) Integration?
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't really compare those things since hey ain't on the same abstraction level nor in the same category.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll probably hear this answer a lot, but it's not a suitable comparison.

Drupal is a ultimately a CMS, Rails is a framework.  Apples to oranges, or perhaps even Apple Juice to oranges.  Out of the box, you fire up Drupal and it does 'things': it has a database structure, the concept of nodes, interfaces blah, blah.  If you fire up Rails you have an empty project.

As far as I know there isn't a "Drupal-on-Rails" project that would be a suitable equivalent.  However, I can attest to the fact that there is an awful lot of Ruby/Rails community and O/S work out there and you might find something suitable. I'd also say that the level of modularity in Ruby and Rails tends to mean that the range of plugins/modules/gems one can use is much greater.

My personal $0.02.  If Drupal does what you need, just use Drupal: it's mature and has a great community.  It's never a good idea to try to port Project X over to a new language as a learning exercise because you'll inevitable fall into the "Well that's how it's done in language X!" trap and become disenchanted with the new system.

If you're wanting to learn Rails (which you should, it's awesome) I'd suggest you'd be best working on a small project and seeing what the ecosystem offers before deciding if it's suitable for the needs of your bigger projects.

Comment: I understand that Rails is not a CMS. However I was under the impression that under a few hours you can collect enough O/S functionality from around the web to match the capabilities of Drupal Core, is this not correct?

Comment: Perhaps _someone_ experienced with the ins-and-outs of Ruby, Gems, and Rails could, but could _anyone_? Who knows really. You still have to put all the pieces together, which I can see taking just about anyone more than a few hours.

Comment: @theIV so how hard is it really? I mean I don't mind taking a week and messing around with it.

Answer (score 3):

I have to second what Govan said, but add to it.

With Drupal, unless you really want to get into building your own modules and extensions you are really interacting with an application. Even when you start using CCK, all you are really doing is flipping switches, filling in forms and defining new options for content on the site.

Ruby on Rails is two things, and neither of them bares much similarity to Drupal. You asked "How hard is it really?". To answer that you need to understand what both Ruby and Rails are. Ruby is a programming language designed to make the life of the object purist programmer simpler and more pleasant. So, the first part of how hard is it is simply to answer "how long do you feel it would take you to learn a completely new programming language, like PHP but different".

Rails is an 'opinionated' framework. It's opinionated in that it lays out how a Ruby web project should be structured, as well as providing multiple APIs for everything from database access to web presentation. To answer the "how hard is it" question for Rails then (assuming you know Ruby by this point), you have to answer how much do you need to learn about cacheing, database design, page design, RESTful programming etc etc.

It's not a short journey. you asked if there is an equivalent to CCK for Ruby and Rails which implies to me that at this point your knowledge of programming is somewhat limited. Ruby and Rails interact with the database. CCK lets you define things in a database. Thus, with Ruby and Rails you are effectively bypassing the wonderful dialogs and forms that CCK provides you with and doing the data definition bits yourself, by hand, in code.

From experience, when I've hired experts in another programming language and framework into my Rails teams, it has taken them between 1 and 3 months to get productive, and a further 3 to 6 months for their productivity to start to raise and approach that of the Rails experts on my team.

Thus, in your particular case, I would not recommend a switch away from Drupal to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I don't mean CCK as in the front-end, I mean something more akin to the Fields API that's coming in D7. I know that Rails itself does not provide anything like Fields, but is there a gem or plugin that does provide this abstraction layer?

Answer (score 3):

- [Drupal (core) on ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/p/drupal) (130k lines of code) is estimated to be 34 years of work worth.
- [Drupal (contributions) on ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/p/drupal-contributions) (modules for Drupal 4-6 (7M lines of code)) is estimated to be 2113 years of work.

That is the power of a community, and that is something that you can never replicate. I remeber there was a guy, who tried to port Drupal to python calling it [drupy](http://drupy.net/), but that project died before something useful ever came out of it. Even if you copy the code, you can never copy the community.

The thing you need to realize, is that each community is different. So even if you find a project that can solve your code needs in a RoR or a different language/framework, it will never be like Drupal and vice versa.

So don't try to find a replacement for Drupal, but go explore and try new things. You might end up learning new things, that you can use for your Drupal projects.

Answer (score 3):

I've read this times and times again that people saying comparing [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) an [ror](/questions/tagged/ror) is comparing apple to orange which is wrong.

I think the saying itself BS. Yes we want to compare apple to orange and find out which is better. We even want to compare apple to steak. Said that, they are different. Yes, we all know. I have limited experience with either. I first thought Drupal was great and can help me build the website I wanted overnight (or over a week or month) then it didn't happen (not blaming Drupal).

My impression is that, Drupal maybe still great but it has a learning curve and needs a lot of other knowledge or talents to use it well and tweak it. RoR on the other hand is a more general framework and needs programming (Drupal needs too actually).

If you are more of a web designer person with a little PHP maybe Drupal is better fit.

If you are more of a web developer type don't want to spend time looking for modules and make them work but rather do them yourself (not really from ground up) then maybe RoR is for you (with the same amount of learning). So yes they are both good for different purpose, background, etc.

For now I will go with RoR (or dJango and other ORANGEs). My 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

Rails, since version 3.0, has officially adopted the once-controversial engine way of incorporating third-party apps. this is roughly the equivalent of Drupal's modules/plug-ins, from a 10k foot perspective. To build a community-based site, you could make use of an engine called, appropriately enough, "Community Engine." http://communityengine.org/features.html"

The Rails ecosystem doesn't have anywhere near the same number of modules Drupalists have available to them, but there are enough good quality ones to cover the chief basics.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has so many strong areas, its hard for just one or two people to recreate it in a decent amount of time with any language. PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.

You have the core node system, taxonomy, aliasing, menus, users, permissions, and modules,  the database api, and form api, among others.

You'd have to know how to assemble all these pieces independently and create the structure necessary for it to all work together.

It would take more than 'a few hours'. I would say, even if you are a ROR master, you're looking at a year to two years of solid consistent work to get the best parts of Drupal for a new system.